# trying to send email using python. Not sure what error message means

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to send an e-mail using Python. I've never done this before and have taken the following code from a tutorial. I'm unsure what the error message is telling me?

```
# import the smtplib module. It should be included in Python by default
import smtplib
# set up the SMTP server
s = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp-mail.outlook.com', port=587)

s.starttls()
s.login('my_email_address@outlook.com', 'my_password')

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

       # create a message
msg = MIMEMultipart()

message_body = 'this is a test'

# setup the parameters of the message
msg['From']='my_email_address@outlook.com'
msg['To']='sending_to_this_address@hotmail.co.uk'
msg['Subject']='This is TEST'

    # add in the message body
msg.attach(MIMEText(message_body, 'plain'))

    # send the message via the server set up earlier.
s.send_message(msg)
```

error message:

```
File "C:\Users\mogwa\Desktop\test.py", line 29, in <module>
    s.send_message(msg)
  File "C:\Python\lib\smtplib.py", line 967, in send_message
    rcpt_options)
  File "C:\Python\lib\smtplib.py", line 888, in sendmail
    raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (554, b'5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:OutboundSpamException; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message WASCL UserAction verdict is not None. Actual verdict is HipNotify, ShowTierUpgrade. OutboundSpamException: WASCL UserAction verdict is not None. Actual verdict is HipNotify, ShowTierUpgrade. [Hostname=LO2P265MB1086.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]')
[Finished in 4.5s]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - Sending Email - STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:OutboundSpamException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778663/c-sharp-sending-email-storedrv-submission-exceptionoutboundspamexception)

Comment: Looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778663/c-sharp-sending-email-storedrv-submission-exceptionoutboundspamexception. More guesses on https://wordpress.org/support/topic/outboundspamexception/

Comment: Thanks, the first link you provided gave the answer. An e-mail was waiting in the inbox telling me i would be unable to send e-mail from the account, until i verified using the link they provided in the e-mail. P.S - i do wish the error messages were more clear. It was such a simple solution, yet the error message might as well have been written in an alien language.